I now get an editing-impossible popup (due to timeout?) when answering - due to new human verification?
Seemingly since the introduction of a new human verification check a day or two ago (the check: just click the checkbox), I have the problem that when I try to answer a question I get a red-background popup saying that editing is currently impossible. I'm guessing this is because of some kind of timeout - the site wanting to recheck my humanity before letting me save a new answer.
I end up losing the text of my answer, just so I can reload the page and start over. This is truly a pain. Is it necessary?
And is it necessary to have the new human verification check repeated when I go from a page on one StackExchange site (e.g. Emacs) to another (e.g. StackOverflow)? How is that helpful?
(I looked for a duplicate question, figuring that others would also have found this new humanity check a bit over the top, but my search didn't find any.

Since this seems to be a recent issue for you, you might want to check this recent change out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403002/preventing-unauthorized-automated-access-to-the-network (Various possible ways you could be affected: You're running some user scripts / extensions that make requests to the site or remove some headers from the sent request, you have some browser setting disabling certain headers, you're accessing the site from a Microsoft IP, or the rate limiting implementation is catching you incorrectly)

@Abdul The general rate-limiting changes (bullet #4) listed in that post won't go live until, at earliest, the last week in October. I'll follow up internally to see if there's more insight we can offer on this question

@AbdulAzizBarkat: None of the things you mention apply to my use. I'm just using the sites from a chrome browser on a Windows 10 PC. I have/use no extensions, and I have no special browser settings.

@Drew are you using any VPN, proxy, etc.?

@Drew Are you comfortable using in-browser developer tools? If so, there's a bit of information we need to diagnose the problem. The next time it happens, could you: 1 - open the network tab in dev tools (F12); 2 - open any request's headers (click on a request); 3 - on any challenge or response page, copy out the value under "Cf-Ray"? That value will let us do some further diagnostics

@Slate: Sorry, no. I'll just wait till someone more knowledgeable and available than I stumbles over it. But beyond the reported problem (about losing edits because of a timeout), the new, REPEATED captcha thing is truly a PITA. Why make us do it once for a StackExchange site and immediately thereafter make us do it again for StackOverflow? And why does this verification itself take so long - even just to display the checkbox?

@AbdulAzizBarkat: I'm on VPN now, but I don't know that that makes a difference. You tell me. (Why should it?) Don't many, many users of SE/SO use it during work, when they're on a VPN? Is this really the new normal: human verification right and left, over and over?

@Drewb it's pretty normal to use a VPN, I'm guessing your VPN for work probably uses Azure which can result in your being caught up in these changes the company is making (Nothing to do with me, I'm just a normal user like you)

@AbdulAzizBarkat: Dunno whether our (Cisco Secure Client) VPN uses Azure. Thanks for the info, anyway.

The problem seems now to have gone away. I'm no longer getting the captcha verification screens. (Hope it stays that way.)
